# flag value will be reset on usercontrol paint event

Tags: c#, .net, user-controls

Created Winusercontrol consist of 1 form and 1 panel.
Draw some text on paint event of panel of user control.
Add reference of usercontrol in my application.

usercontrol code:

```
bool flag=false;
public void Somthing()
{
  ///some code...
  ///
  flag=true;
}

protected void panel_paint(PainteventArgs e)
{
 if(flag==true)
   //draw some text
}
```

Form Application code:

```
private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)   
{
   usercontrol obj=new usercontrol();
   obj.Somthing();
}
```

when i created object of library and call Somthing().
when check in paint event flag value will be false.
so no text will be drawn 
i dont know why flag value will be reset.

Comment: What happens in the block that you have marked with `some code`? If you trigger a paint event in that block the flag is still false.

Comment: Filling dataset..After filling dataset i have to call paint event of usercontrol panel

Comment: As a first try put that flag setting as the first line of the method

Comment: i have check if dataset is not null then flag will be true

Comment: usercontrol obj=new usercontrol();
   obj.Somthing(); Form is refresh so it will reset all values of its default state.And then paint event is called.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the Paint event fires before the Form loaded event, so your flag is false and you'll never be able to add your text.

Try to add an [Invalidate()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invalidate.aspx) to your User Control containing the Panel so it will repaint.

```
public void Somthing()
{
  flag=true;
  this.Invalidate();

  //EDIT: it couldn't be synchronous so force with Update that sends WM_PAINT event
  this.Update();
}
```

Comment: @Means try calling this.Update() after this.Invalidate().

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Invalidate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/598t492a.aspx) method to recall/fire `paint` event after set `flag` value:

> **`Control.Invalidate()`** Invalidates the entire surface of the control and causes the control to be redrawn.

sample code:

```
private bool _flag;

public bool Flag
{
    get { return _flag; }
    set
    {
        _flag = value;
        Invalidate();
    }
}

public void Somthing()
{
    ///some code...
    ///
    Flag = true;
}

protected void panel_paint(PainteventArgs e)
{
    if(Flag == true)
        //draw some text
}
```

Comment: usercontrol obj=new usercontrol();
   obj.Somthing(); Form is refresh so it will reset all values of its default state.And then paint event is called

Answer (score 0):

You should paste full form code. I would create another constructor and pass the value when you create the control. Maybe some event is being fired **before** the form load:

```
bool flag=false;
public void Somthing()
{
  ///some code...
  ///
  flag=true;
}

public void Somthing(bool flagValue)
{
   flag= flagValue;
}
```

Comment: Try what I  wrote. Create another constructor for the class with bool parameter for flag, you will have it set to True since the beginning. You won't have to worry about events order

Comment: Fill dataset in Something method and check if dataset is not null then flag will be true

Answer (score 0):

**Make Flag static.**

```
static bool flag=false;
public void Somthing()
{
  ///some code...  
  flag=true;
}

protected void panel_paint(PainteventArgs e)
{
 if(flag==true)
   //draw some text
   ///Set here
   flag=false;
}
```

Comment: @Means There could be some serious disadvantices by doing that. If the UserControl is show more that once on runtime - the variable data would "survive" even after the UserControl is disposed. Also if you use the UserControl more that once in a single Form, all instances of the UserControl would have to share the data.